# Routing is not working in react. is this a correct way to do it?

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom

I wrapped `app.js` inside `BrowserRouter` in `index.js`.

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import MainRouting from './Routing/MainRouting';
import HomePage from './Pages/HomePage.js/HomePage';
import Login from './component/Login/Login';
import Doctor from './Pages/Doctor/Doctor'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='m-auto'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='/doctor' element={<Doctor />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home Page file

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../../component/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../component/Footer/Footer';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../../component/Home/Home';
import Login from '../../component/Login/Login';
import SignUp from '../../component/SignUp/SignUp';

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div className=''>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/sign-up' element={<SignUp />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Any of my routes are not working.